# How to query multiple params like array in retrofit?

Tags: android, parameters, retrofit2

I'm trying to translate the next endpoint to an api service endpoint of retrofit, but I didn't found how I need to write the sentence.

The endpoint:

```
https://balldontlie.io/api/v1/stats?season[]=2018&player_ids[]=237
```

My try:

```
@GET("stats/{season}{player_ids")
suspend fun getStatsByPlayerId(@Path("player_ids") playerId: String, @Path("season") season: String): Response<DataNetworkModel>
```

And advice to fix this? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
@GET("stats")
suspend fun getStats(
    @Query("seasons[]") seasons: List<Int>
): Response<DataNetworkModel>
```

Calling it this way:

```
service.getStats(listOf(2015, 2016))
```

will give you such URL:

`https://www.balldontlie.io/api/v1/stats?seasons[]=2015&seasons[]=2016`